# Declaring an array of pointers in C++

Tags: c++

When I make an array of integer pointers, I tried this.

```
int *arr = new int*[10];
```

This did not work but the following worked.

```
int **arr = new int*[10];
```

Why do we need double pointer?? And when I deference it, I had to do the following.

```
cout<<arr[0];
```

Why we do not need * in front of arr??
thanks!

Comment: What's this "this did not work"? What is your definition of "it worked"? Use precise language please. We are scientists here.

Comment: An `int*` points to an `int` or the first element of an array of `int`. If you want to point to an `int*` rather than an `int` you need `int**` (pointer to int pointer or to first element of an array of int pointers).

Comment: "I had to do the following." - o'rly?

Comment: I am definitely not a scientist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new int*[10]` allocates an array of ten pointers, and it yields a pointer to the first element of that array. The element type is **itself a pointer**, that's why you end up having a pointer to a pointer (to `int`), which is `int**`. And obviously `int**` isn't convertible to `int*`, so you have to declare `arr` with the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

You are not just "making an array of integer pointers": you are *dynamically allocating them*.

Just like when you dynamically allocate an array of integers you get a single pointer through which to access them:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];
```

when you dynamically allocate an array of pointers-to-integer you get a single pointer through which to access those, too; since your element type is `int*`, adding the extra `*` gives you `int**`:

```
int** ptr = new int*[5];
```

As for dereferencing, I'm not quite sure what you're asking but that's just how the `[]` operator works; it adds `n` to a pointer then dereferences it:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];
*(ptr+1) = 42;         // identical
  ptr[1] = 42;         // to this
```

---

If you forget dynamic allocation and just make a nice array, it's all much simpler:

```
int* array[5];
std::cout << array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is an expression for an 1D array of int

```
int* arr = new int [10]; // pointer to array of 10 int
```

This statement is an expression for a 2D array of int

```
int** arr = new int* [10]; // pointer to 10 pointers to arrays of 10 int
```

To populate the 1D array, you need to do this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arr[i] = val; // where val can be any integer
}
```

To populate the 2D array, you need to do this...

```
int** arr2 = new int*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr2[i] = new int[10];
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arr2[i][j] = val; // where val can be any integer
    }
}
```

The * symbol between the variable type and the variable name is syntax for pointer. It changes type from *int* to *pointer of int*.